# VOIP Codec Preference

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip, telephony, codecs

Do any of you have a preferred codec for VOIP traffic? I guess this is another case where the answer varies depending on use case, equipment, topology, etc...

I'm trying to find an optimal codec to use for remote users telecommuting at home into an asterisk system.

-M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the bandwith (roughly 100 kbps per call), G711 should give you best call quality (and least CPU usage in case Asterisk is transcoding). Otherwise, G729 is a good choice.
These two should be supported by most hard- and softphones. For more exotic codecs, check what your phones support.

Comment: In my experience g729 provides the best PLC algorithm when doing VoIP over the unreliable Internet. g711 call quality degrades rapidly with lost packets. iLBC is okay - but users can complain that voice sounds robotic. Just spend the money on g729 licenses if you don't want a support nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use g729. You will need to buy some licenses from Digium ($10 each, only need to buy enough to support expected concurrent calls). It is money well spent.

Cheers

Comment: +1 for g729.  It's not free, but it's damn good value for money.

Comment: It's also a cheap, easy way to "donate" to the Asterisk project.